# Image is not displayed from Oracle table using servlet

Tags: image, servlets, oracle10g, blob, data-retrieval

After a long trial ,I finally successfully able to upload an **image** to an `oracle database`. At least my code says so. However to check whether the image has been successfully I wrote a `servlet`. After running the `servlet` I get a black screen in my browser and nothing else. The `servlet` code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DisplayImage extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     try {
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
         String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"system","root");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select image from insertimage");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            Blob  b = rs.getBlob("image");
            response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
            response.setContentLength( (int) b.length());
            InputStream is = b.getBinaryStream();
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            byte buf[] = new byte[(int) b.length()];
            is.read(buf);
            os.write(buf);
            os.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
             System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    } 

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } 
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
}

  }
```

By the way, as I am totally new to this, I took extensive help from this [File upload and display demo](http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/fileupload.aspx).
**EDIT :** I get the black screen if only viewed from FF , but if viewed from internal web browser of Eclipse it shows me a single word `upload` . Very strange behaviour!!

Answer (score 0):

Use a debugger, or traces in the code, to see what it executes.

Use Firebug to see what the response contains.

And fix the reading and writing from the blob to the output stream: `InputStream.read()` doesn't necessarily read all the bytes at once. It returns the number of bytes that were actually read. You should loop until this method returns -1 to indicate that everything has been read. Read the [Java IO tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html).

Comment: So how can the image be displayed in the browser? Any other procedure!!??

Comment: also I tried looping like you said by `while(is.read()!=-1)
             {
             is.read(buf);
             }` But it did not give anything else!!

Comment: Do you have any error message in the output? What happens if, instead of `System.out.println(ex.getMessage())` you do `throw new RuntimeException(ex)`? Have you step through the code using a debugger?

Comment: No I don't get any error message neither in the output, nor in the console. I tried `throws RuntimeException` ,it also did not affect.

Comment: By the way, I solved the issue. The display servlet just works fine. The problem is happening in uploading. No image is being inserted during uploading. I counterchecked it using a SQL developer software.